# Chinese Idiom puzzle 18 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

A new puzzle for May-2021

[image]

1. All or nothing
2. Bathe
3. A modern metaphor for a person’s life with extreme luxury and indulgence, without restraint  (有關紂王的典故)
4. Everyone wants to get to a higher position
5. Merits and achievements in war
6. No fixed address
7. A person with extremely bad morals and despicable behavior like an animal
8. Make oneself famous
9. A tooth for a tooth
10. Edo
11. Strength
12. In extreme danger
13. Blood flow like a river
14. The sun is descending behind the mountains in the west. It is a metaphor that things are close to decay or people are approaching old age
15. Substituting fake for real
16. Hippopotamus
17. Pull the tiger's beard. A metaphor for doing something daring and dangerous
18. Give up earthly desire
19. In broad daylight
20. Like bathing in the Spring wind. A metaphor for the feeling of meeting a mentor with sincere teaching
21. The average score
22. Be fair and unbiased
23. The order issued in the morning was changed in the evening. A metaphor for the volatility of government's rules and orders.
24. The well being of the people and the country
25. Loyal vassal
26. Good at understanding people's thinking

A. Orphan

B. Although in a safe environment, one also think of the possibility of danger

C. A flat place. A vast flat land where a horse can gallop. Refers to the vast plain

D. Vicious

E. Offical verbal agreement

F. One divided into two

G. Use eggs to attack a stone. It is a metaphor for attacking the strong with the weak. Will certainly be defeated

H. Once the principal changes, the subordinates also change.

I. Return home with glory (有關項羽的成語)

J. A monkey wears a hat. Used to ridicule someone for stealing his fame and high position without talents

K. Metaphor for secretly changes the content and nature of things

L. Improve

M. Although his face is human, his heart is as fierce as a beast. Described as cruel and despicable

N. Standing like a mainstay in the turbulent currents. An analogy of a person who can take on important responsibilities.

O. Having three highest-ranked government officers in four generations  (A description of 袁绍's family)

P. Full of air. Describe the look of arrogance.

Q. It is a metaphor that the situation is going worse day by day

R. Become independent from one's master and set up his own school

S. Completely empty

T. Popularity among the people

U. Physical battle

V. Literally means that power can uplift a mountain, describing a person’s strength (有關項羽的成語)

W. Spring and Autumn and the Warring States Period

X. Boundless merit

Y. The east wind blew across the horse's ears and disappeared instantly. A metaphor for 'deaf ears/ not listening'

Z. Calculate

Comment: 趾高气扬 is a little bit strange， usually 趾高气昂

Comment: http://chengyu.t086.com/cy12/12539.html

Comment: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%B6%BE%E9%AB%98%E6%B0%94%E6%98%82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 孤注一掷
2 沐浴
3 酒池肉林
4 人往高处
5 战功
6 居无定所
7 衣冠禽兽
8 扬名立万
9 以牙还牙
10 江户
11 力量
12 危如累卵
13 血流成河
14日落西山
15 偷梁换柱
16 河马
17 捋虎须
18 四大皆空
19 光天化日
20 如沐春风
21 平均分
22 大公无私
23 朝令夕改
24 民生国计
25 不二之臣
26 善解人意
A 孤儿
B 居安思危
C 一马平川
D 如狼似虎
E 一言为定
F 一分为二
G 以卵击石
H 一朝天子一朝臣
I 衣锦还乡
J 沐猴而冠
K 偷天换日
L 改善
M 人面兽心
N 中流砥柱
O 四世三公
P 趾高气扬
Q 江河日下
R 自立门户
S 空空如也
T 民心
U 肉搏战
V 力拔山河
W 春秋战国
X 功德无量
Y 马耳东风
Z 计算

Comment: 14 应该是“日薄西山”比较好。